# driver to support to read or write to HIVE from c++ code

Tags: c++, oracle, hive, hiveql, hadoop2

I have core product built on c++ which uses RDBMS namely oracle DB. We are in phase to Big data enable on this product with access to Hive tables. I know from apache spark we have libraries to directly have access to hive tables. 
Now with C++ being base language, what could be possible ways to read/write data on hive on cloudera?
Note: Not looking for pull data to/fro from hive and RDBMS or vice versa.(sqoop). Looking to read or fire query execution on hive itself.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's ODBC hive drivers... Tried them?

Comment: the drivers I got were mostly in jar. how can I use on c++ code for connectivity, Kindly suggest

Comment: I'm fairly sure JAR files are meant only for Java JDBC, not ODBC

Comment: trying cloudera ODBC driver with kerberos authentication. Error : <FAILED!

[Cloudera][Hardy] (34) Error from server: SASL(-1): generic failure: GSSAPI Error: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information (No credentials cache found). >

Comment: Looks like your Hive is secured. Please see installation guide https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/other/connectors/hive-odbc/2-5-12.html

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked out for me. 
1. Install ODBC driver [ODBC](https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/dist/)
2. Go through Installation guide [Installation Guide](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/other/connectors/hive-odbc/2-5-12.html)
3. Open the [Project](https://github.com/anantpukale/Hive_Cpp/) in Visual cpp++ and execute .